# Disable Dynamic Routing capability in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, shiro

With Camel, it is possible to add routes dynamically to the context. And it appears the context is always passed as part of the exchange.

Is there a way to prevent applications from adding routes at runtime? I looked at Shiro security but did not seem to find something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing I can think of is to wrap interactions with these applications using POJO Bean Binding which only passes the body of the Exhchange around and limits access to the Exchange directly...

see http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can extend DefaultContext and add security rule in that.